# How to pass a string as an argument to a batch file

Tags: batch-file, windows-xp

I wish to shorten,

```
 net send abc123 "Message to my dear friends and family"
```

to

```
 Laurie "Message to Laurie"
```

where "Laurie" is a batch file, Laurie.bat, to which the message containing spaces, commas etc gets passed. How do I pass the string as an argument to batch file?

Comment: Only safe way I know to pass data is by piping. Earliest `MSG` command supports it, but `NET SEND` doesn't. You will always have problems with commas and specially with <, | and >. Are you up to use a third party application?

Comment: @LS_dev - we already are, but some continuously refuse to use it. so i thought about "developing" a series of similar bat files for those.

Comment: You didn't comment - was my suggestion unacceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shorten it to this, is that what you meant?

```
Laurie "Message to my dear friends and family"
```

using this:

```
:: laurie.bat
@echo off
net send abc123 "%~1"
```